# How to position a QStaticText by its baseline?

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

How can I achieve baseline positioning for a `QStaticText` object?

For regular text, it's simple: In `QPainter::drawText(position, text)`, the `position.y` coordinate refers to the baseline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that `drawStaticText` positions the text at the baseline, but offsetting the y-coordinate by the font's ascent.

This is meant by `top of the font` in the documentation.

Minimal demo:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QStaticText>

class Window: public QWidget
{
public:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        const int y = 20;

        painter.fillRect(0, y, 200, 1, Qt::black);

        // These all share the same baseline
        painter.drawStaticText(10, y, QStaticText("Üg."));
        painter.drawStaticText(26, y, QStaticText("."));
        painter.drawText(29, y + QFontMetrics(QApplication::font()).ascent(), ".");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Window win;
    win.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at what `QStaticText::size()` returns.

It might be similar to `QTextMetrics::boundingRect()`. The baseline for QFontMetrics is at 3/4 of the height of the bounding rect and reserves space for the letter parts below the base line like with Q, g, p, q, or y.

Could imagine it is similar with the `QStaticText::size()`. Can't test it now, though.